# How can I confirm that Postgres had been installed properly for Heroku use?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am using Heroku and thus the Postgres is needed to be properly installed.

I used the Windows Installer "postgresql-10.1-3-windows-x64.exe" for my installation, and there was not special interruption during the installation.

However, after I deployed a Heroku app on web, and try to run ">pipenv --three" in my cmd windows, there's a message of ' "command" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.', which make me not sure whether Postgres is properly installed.

I also tried to run the command "heroku pg:psql", and the result is as below:-

[heroku pg:psql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJXnr.png)

Is that really because the Postgres is not properly installed, and how can I get it fixed? Thank you in advance for the help!

Environment:-

- Windows 10 Home - 64-bit
- Postgre Installer: postgresql-10.1-3-windows-x64.exe
- Heroku: heroku-cli/6.15.18-fd2097 (win32-x64) node-v9.3.0

Comment: I'm very confused by your question. Heroku doesn't have Windows servers, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it solved, by adding the following into the $PATH.

%APPDATA%\Python\Python36\Scripts

It's not the matter of the installation.

Thx.